# How might one take user input from a web page that is not on a server (and thus has no server-side code) and do something with it?

Tags: html

I have created an HTML form and I have got that part working. I am not sure, however, how to take that information and actually do something with it. This is for a school project so the page isn't accessible on the web. It is just stored on my machine. Thus, I have nothing happening on the server side of things. I have no experience working with php or SQL. I am comfortable with HTML, C#, and JavaScript, and I have experience with Python and Java; I am willing to learn whatever I need, however.

Ideally, what I want to happen is for the page to take the name that the user enters (lets say "John Doe") and navigate to another page based on that name (such as C:\JohnDoe). I have the first name and last name being requested separately, so the space between them won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you will have an index.html file on the root folder, and then multiple users html files (ex: johndoe.html, janedoe.html, etc) alongside it in the same folder, you can write a javascript code just like this one.
The downside is, you must create all html files beforehand, like ivan said, there's nothing you can do to dynamically create files needed using this script only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName">
      <input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName">
      <input type="button" onclick="changePage()" value="Click Here">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function changePage() {
        const firstName = document.querySelector('#firstName').value
        const lastName = document.querySelector('#lastName').value
        const fileNameString = firstName+lastName
        window.location.href = fileNameString+'.html';
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, this does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (imo) is to go ahead and make your local machine a "server" by installing nodejs, which you use by coding some javascript. W3Schools has a tutorial with examples. Your "server" will probably amount to just a few lines of javascript. There is an enormous library of tools to use, such as *express*, which makes it easy to implement a non-trivial server in short order. Many others. Be careful, though, you could get hooked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this might get you on some track, not exactly the best way to do it I'm sure, but some ideas due to the limitations you described. My idea would be saving the name on the input to localStorage or even a Cookie, and then just loading that data on the new page after a redirect. I don't know however if there's some way to 'create' the new page with the name dynamically.

```js
function getUser() {
  var username = document.querySelector('#name').value;
  window.localStorage.setItem('name', username);
  window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  console.log(username);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">

<button type="button" id="nameBtn" onclick="getUser()">Send</button>
```